# Navigation/Scrolling in between the bmp Image in C

Tags: c, printf

I have able to read Bmp Header of Image as per below properties.

**Image Bit-depth    :    1 
Image Attributes   :    1**

I want to scroll/Navigate in between Black and White Image (Bit Depth 1). Without Closing and reopening it (bmp image).

1) Like if input == f or F , Pixel Data goes one by one Forward Direction
Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,....Yn

2) Like if input == r or R, Pixel Data goes one by one Backward Direction
Y123,Y122,Y121,Y120,Y119, ......Y0

3) Also I don't want to read pixels from starting (On Every Read) .
I want to read in between (Vertical Only).
Below is my code .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BitMap {
    short     Type;
    long      Size;
    short     Reserve1;
    short     Reserve2;
    long      OffBits;
    long      biSize;
    long      biWidth;
    long      biHeight;
    short     biPlanes;
    short    biBitCount;
    long      biCompression;
    long      biSizeImage;
    long      biXPelsPerMeter;
    long      biYPelsPerMeter;
    long      biClrUsed;
    long      biClrImportant; } Header;

unsigned char DummyValueRead ; unsigned char pixelValue =0 ;

int Horizontal= 0 ,Vertical = 0 ;

long  myPalette[2]; long  HeaderBytes;

unsigned char bPadding ;  long wBytesPerRow ;  unsigned char
bAdditionalBitsPerRow ;  FILE  *BMPFile;  void SendPixelValues();
unsigned char input ;

int main( void ) {
    BMPFile = fopen ("mul.bmp", "r");
    if (BMPFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Image Not Found !!!!!!");
        return -1;
    }

    fread(&Header.Type,                                    sizeof(Header.Type), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.Size,                                       sizeof(Header.Size), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.Reserve1,                           sizeof(Header.Reserve1) , 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.Reserve2,                           sizeof(Header.Reserve2) , 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.OffBits,                                sizeof(Header.OffBits), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biSize,                                  sizeof(Header.biSize), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biWidth,                             sizeof(Header.biWidth), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biHeight,                            sizeof(Header.biHeight) , 1, BMPFile);

    fread(&Header.biPlanes,                           sizeof(Header.biClrUsed),  1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biBitCount,                      sizeof(Header.biBitCount), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biCompression,              sizeof(Header.biCompression), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biSizeImage,                    sizeof(Header.biSizeImage), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biXPelsPerMeter,         sizeof(Header.biXPelsPerMeter), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biYPelsPerMeter,         sizeof(Header.biYPelsPerMeter), 1, BMPFile);

    fread(&Header.biClrUsed,                        sizeof(Header.biClrUsed), 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.biClrImportant,             sizeof(Header.biClrImportant),  1, BMPFile);

    fseek(BMPFile,Header.OffBits,SEEK_SET) ;

    printf("\nType:%hd   and Type in  %x\n", Header.Type,Header.Type);
    printf("Size:%ld\n", Header.Size);
    printf("Reserve1:%hd\n", Header.Reserve1);
    printf("Reserve2:%hd\n", Header.Reserve2);
    printf("OffBits:%ld\n", Header.OffBits);
    printf("biSize:%ld\n", Header.biSize);
    printf("Width:                         %ld\n", Header.biWidth);
    printf("Height:                         %ld\n", Header.biHeight);
    printf("biPlanes:%hd\n", Header.biPlanes);
    printf("biBitCount:%hd\n", Header.biBitCount);
    printf("biCompression:%ld\n", Header.biCompression);
    printf("biSizeImage:%ld\n", Header.biSizeImage);
    printf("biXPelsPerMeter:%ld\n", Header.biXPelsPerMeter);
    printf("biYPelsPerMeter:%ld\n", Header.biYPelsPerMeter);
    printf("biClrUsed:%ld\n", Header.biClrUsed);
    printf("biClrImportant:%ld\n\n", Header.biClrImportant);

    wBytesPerRow =Header.biWidth/8;
    bAdditionalBitsPerRow = Header.biWidth    %    8;
    bPadding = (4 - ((wBytesPerRow + (bAdditionalBitsPerRow?1:0)   ) % 4  )   )    %4;
    HeaderBytes = Header.biWidth/8  ;

    for(Vertical = 0 ;    Vertical <  Header.biHeight ;  Vertical ++)
    {
        printf("Sr. No. %d  \n",Vertical) ;
        scanf("%c",&input) ;
        if(input =='r' || input =='R' )          // Reverse Direction
        {
            //   fseek(BMPFile,((4*968) + 3), SEEK_SET );
            SendPixelValues() ;
        }
        if(input =='f' || input =='F' )          // Forward Direction
            SendPixelValues() ;
        printf("\n")  ;

    }
    fclose(BMPFile);

    return 0;
}

unsigned int bAdditionalBitsPerRowCount =
        0,bPaddingCount=0; void SendPixelValues() {

    for(Horizontal = 0 ; Horizontal <  HeaderBytes ;  Horizontal++)
    {
        fread(&pixelValue, sizeof(pixelValue), 1, BMPFile);
        printf("0x%x  ",pixelValue)  ;
    }
    if(bAdditionalBitsPerRow > 0)
    {
        fread(&DummyValueRead , sizeof(DummyValueRead ), 1, BMPFile);
        bAdditionalBitsPerRow++;
        printf("bAdditionalBitsPerRowCount %d",bAdditionalBitsPerRowCount);
    }
    for(Horizontal = 0 ;   Horizontal <  bPadding;  Horizontal++)
    {
        fread(&DummyValueRead , sizeof(DummyValueRead ), 1, BMPFile);
        bPaddingCount++;
    }
    printf("bPaddingCount = %d",bPaddingCount) ;
}
```

[image]
Thanks
Karan

Comment: Please re-port without the leading `>` in code.

Comment: The `>` in your code quote break your [mcve]. Please remove them.

Comment: Why you do not read the whole header at once `fread(&Header,              sizeof Header, 1, BMPFile);`?

Comment: @i486 I also need width and height of the Image. How do I navigate in between the image?

Comment: Your file header is wrong, you are skipping the color table, that's a problem with 1-bit bitmap. Also it's hard to offset x/y values in 1-bit bitmap if you don't know what you are doing. I recommend using an image library.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani 
Yes , I am skipping the color table
But I am able to read Bmp Header and Pixels Values Correctly for 1-bit  (Two Color) black and white  Image.. I only need to navigate in between the image with offset value ..

Comment: Thanks for Update..@Barmak Shemirani
Do I really need palette. The code in question is worked good for me .
Also I don't want to redraw the image (As example you posted).
May be redraw required palette.
I Just want to use pixel data as in SendPixelValues() and modification required in this code I have to scroll in pixel data as image attached in question.
Pixel Data goes one by one Forward Direction Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,....Yn
Pixel Data goes one by one Backward Direction Y123,Y122,Y121,Y120,Y119, ......Y0
How do I calculation offset for that.? Thanks Karan

Answer (score 0):

1-bit bitmap format has 8 bytes for its palette, you have to read those 8 bytes before reading the pixels.

There are 8 pixels packed in to one byte. You have to separate the bits and write them accordingly. Bitmap can have width padding, you have to calculate the padding for the input file as well as output file.

Make sure to read/write the file in binary (it matters in Windows).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct BITMAPFILEHEADER {
    short bfType;
    int bfSize;
    short bfReserved1;
    short bfReserved2;
    int bfOffBits;
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER {
    int biSize;
    int biWidth;
    int biHeight;
    short biPlanes;
    short biBitCount;
    int biCompression;
    int biSizeImage;
    int biXPelsPerMeter;
    int biYPelsPerMeter;
    int biClrUsed;
    int biClrImportant;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(void) 
{
    //set X and Y offset:
    int x0 = 10;
    int y0 = 10;

    if(sizeof(short) != 2 ||
        sizeof(int) != 4 ||
        sizeof(struct BITMAPFILEHEADER) != 14 ||
        sizeof(struct BITMAPINFOHEADER) != 40)
    {
        printf("Error, wrong structure size...");
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *fin = fopen("mul.bmp", "rb");
    FILE *fout = fopen("output.bmp", "wb");
    if(fin == NULL)
    {
        printf("Image Not Found !!!!!!");
        return -1;
    }

    struct BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
    struct BITMAPINFOHEADER info;

    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, fin);
    fread(&info, sizeof(info), 1, fin);

    if (info.biBitCount != 1)
    {
        printf("Error, not 1-bit bitmap\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int old_width = info.biWidth;
    int old_height = info.biHeight;
    int bitcount = info.biBitCount;
    int width_in_bytes = ((old_width * bitcount + 31) / 32) * 4;
    char palette[8];
    fread(palette, 1, sizeof(palette), fin);

    int new_width = old_width - x0;
    int new_height = old_height - y0;

    //convert to 24-bit bitmap for output file
    info.biBitCount = 24;
    info.biWidth = new_width;
    info.biHeight = new_height;
    info.biSizeImage = ((info.biHeight * bitcount + 31) / 32) * info.biWidth;
    header.bfSize = 54 + info.biSizeImage;
    header.bfOffBits = 54;

    fwrite(&header, 1, sizeof(header), fout);
    fwrite(&info, 1, sizeof(info), fout);

    char *bytes_read = malloc(width_in_bytes);
    char black[3] = { 0 };
    char white[3] = { 255,255,255 };
    for(int y = 0; y < old_height; y++)
    {
        fread(bytes_read, 1, width_in_bytes, fin);

        int width_index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < width_in_bytes; i++)
        {
            //8 pixels are packed in to 1 byte
            //separate the bits, write them as bytes in 24-bit format
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                width_index = i * 8 + j;
                if(width_index < x0) continue;
                if(width_index - x0 >= new_width) break;

                int pixel = (bytes_read[i] & (1 << (8 - j)));

                if(pixel)
                    fwrite(white, 1, 3, fout);
                else
                    fwrite(black, 1, 3, fout);
            }
        }

        //add padding to output file
        int m = width_index % 4;
        if(m)
            fwrite(black, 1, m, fout);
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Update..@Barmak Shemirani Do I really need palette. The code in question is worked good for me . Also I don't want to redraw the image (As example you posted). May be redraw required palette. I Just want to use pixel data as in SendPixelValues() and modification required in this code I have to scroll in pixel data as image attached in question. Pixel Data goes one by one Forward Direction Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,....Yn Pixel Data goes one by one Backward Direction Y123,Y122,Y121,Y120,Y119, ......Y0 How do I calculation offset for that.? Thanks Karan Please Update..

Comment: I don't understand your comment. 1-bit image has a palette that's 8 bytes long. I showed how to set the offset with `x0` and `y0`, and how to read all the pixels.